# Write Xlsx file with python - Blank Lines on Excel file

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to code a python script to parse a text file in an excel sheet.

On this script, I'm trying to write a list of lists on the Xlsx file where each list's element is written in a single line of the Sheet.

The problem is when I have two equals elements and they appear sequentially and using both python modules to generate the excel file (xlsxwriter and openpyxl) they just write one of the equals elements and they write a blank line instead of the second element.

*Example*:

The input list is:

```
list = [['dog', 'cat', 'bat', 'jaguar'], ['dog', 'cat', 'bat', 'jaguar']]
```

The excel file is written like this:

```
      A      B       C      D
   1 dog    cat     bat    jaguar
   2 blank line
```

Does anyone know if I am doing anything wrong?

This is my code:

```
def criaExcel(filename, regras):

    nomeDoArquivo = filename.rstrip('.wri')+'.xlsx'

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(nomeDoArquivo)

    planilha = workbook.add_worksheet('Rules')

    indice = ''

    for regra in regras:

        indice = str(regras.index(regra)+1)

        planilha.write('A'+ indice, regra[0])
        planilha.write('B'+ indice, regra[1])
        planilha.write('C'+ indice, regra[2])
        planilha.write('D'+ indice, regra[3])
        planilha.write('E'+ indice, regra[4])
        planilha.write('F'+ indice, regra[5])
        planilha.write('G'+ indice, regra[6])


    workbook.close()




def parseV3(filename):

    manipulador = open(filename, 'r', encoding="Latin-1")

    regras  = []
    regras.append(['Zona', 'Origem', 'Destino', 'Serviço', 'Ação', 'Status', 'Comentário'])

    zona = origem = destino = servico = acao = status = comentario = ''

    padraoCabecalho = re.compile('^Rule.+ (Allow|Deny) Service Any -> (.*) (\(Enabled\)|\(Disabled\))')

    padraoInformacoes = re.compile('^\s{7,8}IP: (.*) -> (.*)  .*')

    padroaComentario = re.compile('^Comment:                   (.*)')


    for linha in manipulador:


        if linha.startswith('From '):

           zonaTemp = linha.rstrip().lstrip('From ')

           if zona == '':
               zona = zonaTemp

           elif zona != zonaTemp:
              zona = zonaTemp


        elif padraoCabecalho.match(linha):

            objetos = padraoCabecalho.match(linha)

            acao, servico, status = objetos.groups()


        elif padraoInformacoes.match(linha):

             objetos = padraoInformacoes.match(linha)

             origem, destino = objetos.groups()


        elif padroaComentario.match(linha):

              objeto = padroaComentario.match(linha)

              comentario = objeto.group(1)

              regras.append([zona, origem, destino, servico, acao, status, comentario])


        elif linha.rstrip() == '#Firewall : Access Rules_END':
            break

    manipulador.close()

    criaExcel(filename, regras)
```

Comment: Post your code otherwise we can't help you identify what is wrong.

Comment: Read about [mcve]

Comment: @Nicarus done man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues in the sample code.

The first is that `index()` probably isn't doing what you think it is doing. A better approach would be to use `enumerate()`.

Also, you don't have to use (or create) `A1` style strings for `write()`. It also accepts `row, col` notation, which would be better in this case.

For example:

```
import xlsxwriter


def criaExcel(filename, regras):

    nomeDoArquivo = filename.rstrip('.wri')+'.xlsx'

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(nomeDoArquivo)

    planilha = workbook.add_worksheet('Rules')

    for row_num, regra in enumerate(regras):

        planilha.write(row_num, 0, regra[0])
        planilha.write(row_num, 1, regra[1])
        planilha.write(row_num, 2, regra[2])
        planilha.write(row_num, 3, regra[3])
        planilha.write(row_num, 4, regra[4])
        planilha.write(row_num, 5, regra[5])
        planilha.write(row_num, 6, regra[6])

    workbook.close()


regras = [['dog', 'cat', 'bat', 'jaguar', 'cat', 'eel', 'cow'],
          ['dog', 'cat', 'bat', 'jaguar', 'cat', 'eel', 'cow']]


criaExcel('test.wri', regras)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It works now perfectly man! Thaks a lot and the enumerate method is amazing and useful. Thank you so much man!